# GYB (got your back) Python install on Mac Yosemite triggers py2exe error

Tags: python, osx-yosemite

I would like to backup the contents of my gmail account.
A recommended solution is Python module:
https://github.com/jay0lee/got-your-back/releases

But within its setup.py file there is a reference to Windows py2exe, which triggers this message when I run setup.py install:

```
  File "setup.py", line 2, in <module>
    import py2exe, sys, os
ImportError: No module named py2exe
```

Comment: Have you downloaded the source-code zip, not the windows one ?

Comment: Good question. I should have mentioned that I downloaded the zip file and unzipped it. There is a reference to p2exe in setup.py.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [installation on mac](https://github.com/jay0lee/got-your-back/wiki#mac-and-linux-users-2) page, you don't have to run setup.py to use the software :

> Now run:
>
> ```
> python gyb.py --email youremail@gmail.com --action estimate
> ```